# HighChart Title text implemented HTML Style is not applying in exporting files

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, styles

I have added `<br/>` and `&nbsp;` HTML tags in HighChart titles. I can see that style changes in chart view but when we exporting into PNG, JPEG images... Text style was unable to apply in the exported images. Please refer sample images below

Please refer the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uXg9t/172/

**Chart View:**

[image]

**Exported View:**

[image]

Any suggestion to export Title as given in the Chart View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer of @Halvor Strand hits the home, but additionally there is need to change the title structure, because SVG won't generate correctly during exporting. It's happening because `</br>`'s, but to solve this problem, for example you can place every title line in different `<span>` element with `style="display: block;"` set on it. Take a look on the code:

```
    title: {
        useHTML: true,
        text: '<span style="display: block;">Header Text in Line1</span><span style="display: block;">Line 2 Text</span><span style="display: block;">Line 3 Text</span>',
        style: {
            "text-align": "center"
        }
    }
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/m052y9ud/

Answer (score 1):

You can set `allowHTML` to `true`, which is an experimental feature for exporting. [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.allowHTML) says:

> `allowHTML: Boolean` Since 4.1.8
>
> Experimental setting to allow HTML inside the chart (added through the `useHTML` options), directly in the exported image. This allows you to preserve complicated HTML structures like tables or bi-directional text in exported charts.
>
> Disclaimer: The HTML is rendered in a `foreignObject` tag in the generated SVG. The official export server is based on PhantomJS, which supports this, but other SVG clients, like Batik, does not support it. This also applies to downloaded SVG that you want to open in a desktop client.
>
> Defaults to `false`.

In your case, it can look something like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uXg9t/177/)):

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    // ...
    exporting: {
        enabled: true,
        allowHTML: true,
        chartOptions: {
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```